# OMNeT++: function hasVisualizer() not found

Tags: omnet++, inet, rpl

i use omnetpp-5.7.1, inet-4.2.10, when i build PRL, there is no errors.

But when I run .ini(rpl/simulations), there is a problem. Function is not found, why?

Can someone help me? Many thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eq1F7.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4QNP.png)

I set inet link with static style and use gcc compiler, I dont know if the setings have relation with problem.